# Finding a variable name while using LLVM Interpreter

Tags: c++, llvm, lli

When using LLVM Interpreter(Aka `lli`), an `Instruction` object is run in `Interpreter::run()` function like as in the code.

```
void Interpreter::run() {
    while (!ECStack.empty()) {
    // Interpret a single instruction & increment the "PC".
    ExecutionContext &SF = ECStack.back();  // Current stack frame
    Instruction &I = *SF.CurInst++;         // Increment before execute

    // Track the number of dynamic instructions executed.
    ++NumDynamicInsts;
    DEBUG(dbgs() << "About to interpret: " << I << "\n");

    visit(I);   // Dispatch to one of the visit* methods...
  }
}
```

A line with `DEBUG` preprocessor will print the instruction that was written in .ll file like this.

> About to interpret: %retval = alloca i32, align 4

How can I get the LLVM IR variable's name?

In this situation it will be `%retval`.

Comment: Simply `I.getName()`.

Comment: @arrowd Wow, why I didn't notice it? Poor me... Thank you.